# Select from database, whose name is a value returned from other field

Tags: sql-server, left-join

i have a strange situation - i need to select from a database, but its name is in a field of another table.
The customer has an ERP where every mandant is in own database and they have 5 different mandants. All of them have exactly the same structure. So for example i need to get product info from more of the mandants. I have a table where one field contains name of the database and one record ID, one is just identity. So i want to do something like

```sql
SELECT relations.id, relations.database, products.warehouse, products.image FROM relations WHERE id = xxxx
LEFT JOIN [relations.database].dbo.products
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This almost certainly suggests a (major) design flaw in my opinion. If you are separating the databases then you aren't doing to be able to do this without: 1. `LEFT JOIN`ing to *every database*, which won't scale, or 2. Using dynamic SQL for *all* your queries that need to reference all the databases, which is almost always a nightmare (and a real (security) concern if you have no idea what you're doing).

Comment: you can't dynamize the database name without using dynamic sql. Probably you can just hardcode some view if it's only 5 databases

Comment: This looks like a tenanted database model, where everything for a specific client is within a database instance. This does make reporting harder but you would generally use a data warehouse populated from all databases where you can report and filter by client or aggregate for all clients

Comment: Thom A: well, not my idea. The ERP is simply like that. It causes lots of problems. More over every year is in separate database and records not finished in year 2022 (not paid invoices etc.) are transferred to 2023. 
Stu: well, i use this for e.g. invoices 3 years back. At the moment i solved it asi multiple queries inside a loop through the relation table results. Just thinking - as this will only be needed to link a master product card to possible records in the ERP (that's so stupid, that they need a separate record in products for each warehouse and variant etc. And we need a central one

Comment: So there can be a master product card linked to 25 warehouses in one database, 5 in another, 1 in another.  And i think that i won't have the problem with thousands of queries, as i select only relations for 1 master product and it will be at most several tens of results. So i can keep it as loop and more queries...

Answer (score 0):

If you always need only this 5 databases, you just can mark every database with label, like this

```
select * from 
  relations 
left join (
    select 'Database1' as database_for_extraction,* from Database1.dbo.products
    union all select 'Database2' as database_for_extraction,* from Database2.dbo.products
    union all select 'Database3' as database_for_extraction,* from Database3.dbo.products
    union all select 'Database4' as database_for_extraction,* from Database4.dbo.products
    union all select 'Database5' as database_for_extraction,* from Database5.dbo.products) products on products.database_for_extraction = relations.database
```

It can be slow, it's would be better if you pick only needed rows first.
But if list of databases can be changed, dynamic SQL is only option.

Comment: Hi, thanks. The problem is that the list can change (and most probably really will, they are expanding quickly) and in reality it is not 5, now it is 9. at the end i select just from the relation table from c# code and then loop through the result and  make a new query to the needed database. Now it's ok, but i am afraid that once when there will be much more relations it would be too slow.